# Non-apple adapter for iPhone

Tags: iphone

I bought a used iPhone 3G.  Came with an adapter called I-Tec electronics. Will this damage my iPhone? A warning message appears when I charge it.  But it does charge.  Just want to know if it will damage iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

Looking up for the I-Tec T7001 Iphone 3G charger is safe to use, it is UL approved.

> COMPATIBLE WITH IPHONE & IPHONE 3G/3GS; CHARGES IPHONE FROM ANY WALL
>   OUTLET; FEATURES A SNAP-IN POWER UNIT TO ALLOW USER TO CONTINUE USING
>   PHONE WITHOUT INTERRUPTIONS WHILE CHARGING; FOLD-AWAY PRONGS FOR EASY
>   TRANSPORTATION; 6-FOOT LONG CABLE; UL APPROVED

<sub>UL is one of several companies approved to perform safety testing by the US federal agency Occupational Safety and Health Administration (OSHA)</sub>

Comment: Any source @Buscar?

Comment: What does "UL approved" even mean ? Some kind of safety norm ? I've seen lots of chinese chargers/power supplies that have all kinds of safety logos and certifications on them (ROHS, CE, etc) and yet what you can find inside them is always scary and definitely not safe.